# Не открыть скобки в редакторе Sublime Text 3

Tags: python-3.x, sublime-text-3, anaconda

После установки плагина Anaconda изменилось поведение странным образом: во все .py файлах перестали открываться скобки 8(( Как это исправить не удаляя Анаконду? может кто сталкивался? Любую функцию пишу например str - даже если в меню выбрать нажать таб или энтер ничего не происходит, и шифт 9 тоже ничего не происходит - курсор стоит на месте. А если выделить чтонить и нажать шифт 9 то текст оборачивается в скобки... Что просиходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был конфликт с плагином Jedi - удалил и все ок!

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/197370)

Comment: @MedvedevDev, это не дополнение вопроса. Это решение вопроса.